# How to select item from Spinner then do somthing on button click?

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner, buttonclick

I have `spinner` with 3 items and I want to do different thing for each selected items, Like if the selected item is **"add" then add 2 numbers via button click**, I have implemented a code it works but not on button click how do I connect that.

This is my code.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String uints = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                            double r1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
                            double r2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
                            double rout = r1 + r2;
                            textView.setText(Double.toString(rout));
                            break;

                        case 1:

                            double r12 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
                            double r22 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
                            double rout2 = r12 - r22;
                            textView.setText(Double.toString(rout2));

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            double r13 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
                            double r23 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
                            double rout3 = r13 / r23;
                            textView.setText(Double.toString(rout3));
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you want the selected spinner item on button click so you can directly get the selected item by the spinner without any listener.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               switch(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                    //Do whatever you want
               }
            }
}
```

you can get selected item's ID, View, position or item itself by using default functions.

```
spinner.getSelectedItemId()
spinner.getSelectedItemView()
spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
spinner.getSelectedItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not write the `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` inside the `button.setOnClickListener`.

First add the `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` and store the value in any `integer`.

Now compare the `interger` value at `button.setOnClickListener` and perform the operation.

Here's the code -

```
int selectedPosition = 0;
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
    selectedPosition = position;
}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){
}
});


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    switch (selectedPosition) {

        case 0:
            double r1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
            double r2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
            double rout = r1 + r2;
            textView.setText(Double.toString(rout));
            break;

        case 1:

            double r12 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
            double r22 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
            double rout2 = r12 - r22;
            textView.setText(Double.toString(rout2));

            break;
        case 2:
            double r13 = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
            double r23 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
            double rout3 = r13 / r23;
            textView.setText(Double.toString(rout3));
            break;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: i tried this as i understand the app crashes on start.but not sure wut u mean about compare i put on button.setClick  textView.setText(Double.toString(value)); which vaule is the double i stored in switch case

Comment: @Ajed I have updated the code as far as I can understand.